# In React native, what is the exception Invariant Violation: expected a component class got div?

Tags: react-native

I'm making a React Native app and got the error Invariant Violation: expected a component class got div

What does that mean?

Here's the app:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  Text,
  View,
  AppRegistry
} = React;

var Select = require('react-select');

var options = [
  { value: 'val1', label: 'Value 1' },
  { value: 'val2', label: 'Value 2' },
];


var MyApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>I am selecting:</Text>
        <Select
            name="form-field-name"
            value="val1"
            options={options}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => MyApp);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-select` is a project for React for the web, not for React Native. When you try to use it, React Native sees that it is built using HTML and complains about the `<div>` tag. You can't simply use components built for the web and expect them to work for React Native.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I figured that after a bunch of head scratching on why it didn't work.

Comment: What do you recommend for getting a select on mobile with RN?

Comment: I'm interested in what the solution is though. I have another project where I just rendered a `<Text>` component on a whim and get this error. What should I attempt to render instead?

Comment: If you got that with a Text node then are you sure you're actually returning it and that you have required it? It's generally raised when what you think is a node is actually a null value.